# Bundle 2 tables in 1 Inner Join

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

[image]I have the sql code below. It works but when I run the query, it repeats the data more than one time. I believe it has something to do with the Inner Join. Since it is Inner Joining twice the data is repeating twice in the report. Any help is appreciated

```
SELECT NewRelative.FullName, GiftGave.EventName, GiftGave.EventDate, GiftGave.AmountGiven, GiftGave.Notes, GiftRcvd.EventName
FROM (NewRelative INNER JOIN GiftGave ON NewRelative.FullName = GiftGave.FullName) INNER JOIN GiftRcvd ON NewRelative.FullName = GiftRcvd.FullName
WHERE (((NewRelative.FullName)=[forms]![FormRelativeReport]![TxtPickRelative]));
```

Comment: Show the results that you are getting and the results you would like to get.  The description of the problem is meaningless without an example.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT will help if the duplicate rowd are exactly the same

Comment: Just added a screenshot of it. I don't want to see the highlighted entry.

Comment: the second join needs to look for a relation between event names also

Comment: You will need to filter the data by more than just FullName if you only want one row, where there is more than one row of data for a given FullName value